# SARS-COV-2 replication speed

Tags: virology, pcr, coronavirus, dna-replication

What is the speed of replication of SC2? Any information, including in vitro data would be appreciated.

I would be interested to know the length of SC2 eclipse period, latent period and something like burst size.

Alternatively, per day CT values of qtPCR of COVID+ subjects would be also helpful.

Answer (score 1):

According to Amy Rosenfeld, it is about 8 hours eclipse and 18-24 hours until "its done". Not sure if it means until burst or until the latent period is over. These times are in vitro and are cell line dependent. In vivo might be different. Burst size also cell depndent. Source: https://youtu.be/NP56XjzyPfQ?t=1301

In this video https://youtu.be/4S3DXXtRZZg?t=152, it is said, that each cell can produce up to 600k viral particles of SC2, but I'm not sure, what is exactly meant by the number. Later in that video: https://youtu.be/4S3DXXtRZZg?t=187 it is said, that the virus seems not to kill cells for about 5-6 days.